# How to estimate the storage room for txt file when writing data to SD card module?

Tags: sd-card

I'm planning to use Arduino UNO to do some measurements and record it in a SD card module. The measurements is going to last for a year or 20 month. I need some advice on how to estimate how long can the SD card storage last without overflow. Right now I'm doing measurements every second, each second contains 13 lines of data, each line is roughly 30 characters. How big is the txt file gonna be if I left the Arduino unit recording for a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a multiplication problem.

13 lines times 30 characters is 390 bytes per measurement.

There are 86400 seconds in one day.

86400 * 390 = 33,696,000

So that's around 34 megabytes per day.

After 1 year it would be:

365 * 33.696 = 12299 MB or a little more than 12 GB.

Comment: I just realized I put 86400 in my calculator as 68400.  I am editing to correct now.

Answer (score 0):

What type of SD card are you using? Based on the capacity, you can calculate SD card storage time to overflow with data/second. Since a character has a size of one byte, the amount of data used per day should be 30 * 13 * 86400 (sec/day) = 33696000 bytes or 0.033696 gb per day.